# Firebase phone auth error "TOO_LONG" on iPad (using test number)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have submitted an iOS app for review and the apple team has rejected it saying they cannot sign in on an iPad using the test number I provided. I know the test number works on my physical iPhone and it also works on an Xcode iPad simulator, however I do not have a physical iPad to test on.

Screenshot from them:

[screenshot from apple review team](https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple112/v4/ff/70/85/ff70851b-5524-75c1-bbfe-d8ab06c625b8/Screenshot-0627-121454.png?accessKey=1656609796_3698688243781134556_FVth8VpTAxJcGIq8cFv2ScmmrBC1EqqsmM938tPrw6kulsOtoy9Cg2cFnq%2B5xb0o94MNHdkNwqabJCAhfzuxzrfDYDpb9b68a6mLrVq5WD9QYT8ftB4UhLMFED6ZPd0ko%2FWVpp4xUsPoHxMufBnJY%2BvLuDha0Dp0y0YS%2FCmw0DQsG2pvodiRK65eopWS7HK%2F)

here is the phone number handling func:

```
private func startAuth(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let areaPhoneNum = "+\(self.getCountryCode() + self.phoneNum)"
        print(areaPhoneNum)
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(areaPhoneNum, uiDelegate: nil) { [weak self] verificationID, error in
            if let verificationID = verificationID {
                self?.verificationID = verificationID
                completion(true)
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error)
                self?.authPhoneErrorMess = error.localizedDescription
                self?.isLoading = false
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Why would an error message print on a valid test number?

Comment: maybe the reviewer's country code is not the same as yours.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine This is entirely possible, I tried using any country code other than US +1 and 8/10 times it gave me the same error message the app reviewer had. I am still waiting for review so I will find out soon.